# cant pass text string into jquery function?

Tags: jquery, string, debugging, function

What's wrong with my jquery script?

Here's the script

```
function debug(message){
  $("body").append("<div id=\"debug\">"+ $(message) +"</div>"):
}
debug("show this debug message in the div");
```

Here's the resulting html I get

```
<div id="debug">[object Object]</div>
```

The html that I expect is this

```
<div id="debug">show this debug message in the div</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pasting an object in, $(message), instead of the variable message.  Try this:

```
    function debug(message){
      $("body").append("<div id=\"debug\">"+ message +"</div>"):
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You're converting a string to a jquery object using `$(message)`. basically, you're making `message` no longer a string but a selector to jquery. Try the following:

```
function debug(message){
  $('body').append($('<div>').attr('id','debug').text(message));
}
```

note I use .attr and .text as this is a tad bid safer when appending information.

**EDIT** Also, another thing to note: ID is a unique identifier in HTML. for this reason, if you're calling this function multiple times, you may want to either assign a perm. "div" to alter the `.text()` value of, or consider using a debug [CSS] class for the div.

Comment: Good thing I refreshed prior to posting.. This was exactly what I was going to say. +1

Comment: & @Josh - This approach is a lot cleaner.  I don't really like putting HTML in my JavaScript.  +1.

Comment: @Josh: Don't forget to mark answers that help you as "Accepted". This gives credit to the posters, but also makes this question a great resource to future visitors with the same problem. (I notice you have 5 other questions, 4 with answers--all of which have no accepted answers).