# Wrapping $( ) around String returns nothing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to strip HTML tags from a string following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643853/cant-pass-text-string-into-jquery-function). The string I'm trying to strip the tags from is a JSON property named item.content. So my code looks like this:

```
$(item.content).text();
```

If the value of `item.content` is the following it works great:

> El mexicano Marco Rodríguez será el árbitro del duelo entre Corinthians y Al Ahly

If however, `item.content` is this, I get an error:

> 'Prefiero ganar la Décima, aunque el Barça nos saque 25 puntos', dice Iker Casillas

The error is `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression`. I'm guessing this is because of the single quotes, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any advice?

Comment: That's not at all what `$()` does, and nothing in the post you linked to indicates that it does what you think it does. You can't use it for this purpose. You either give it a selector, and it will traverse the DOM to find matching elements, or you give it an HTML fragment and it will turn it into disconnected DOM nodes.

Comment: In $(....), the ... must refer to a valid selector. How is the variable item.content going to help ?

Comment: Then how can I use the text() function if I don't wrap item.content in $()?

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ to see what selectors are. That's where you're wrong.

Comment: $( ) is the equivalent for jQuery( ) selector. it should be something like $('ul') or $('div.whatever') based on your dom.

Comment: On this page, press F12 and type `$("this is some text").text()`.  You will see it returns nothing.  Without a parent element the text is not found.  Try the same with `$("<div>this is some text</div>").text()`.  That works.  You need an element in order to use `text()`.

Comment: I don't see why you got so many down votes. There's nothing wrong with not knowing how to do something.

Comment: Honestly, this whole upvote / downvote system is why I hate posting questions on Stack Overflow. I always wonder if I'm going to get a helpful answer or someone is just waiting to jump down my throat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the .text()(or any other jQuery) function on that string, you need to add it to an element so you can use any jQuery methods on it.  Ex.

```
$('<div/>').text(item.content).text() // <-- see how element is created first to add the string.. then use jQuery's text() method to get the string
```

Or using a valid string with elements

```
$('<div>' + item.content + '</div>').text()
```

as @Kevin B noted in the comments..

Using

```
$('<div/>').html(item.content).text()
```

is correct way for this example because you want to preserve the html

Comment: Right, that's what I thought I might have to do. Thx.

Comment: Note however you actually want `$('<div/>').html(item.content).text()`, otherwise html within the `item.content` will be printed as a string and then not removed.

Answer (score 0):

See this example to see how selectors work. You select from a DOM-id or classname. (Use element inspector from Chrome or FireBug to see your console's values or replace `console.log` with `alert`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    console.log($('#your_text').html());
  });
</script>

<span id="your_text">hello, this is my value</span>
```